# Second sprite movement relative to the first

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Advice please:
cocos2d:I have two sprites, I ask a second position relative to the first? Ie can I move the first sprite, and when I move it, the second sprite should be, for example, by 20 px above pervogo.T.e also moves with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do this , the easiest is :

```
 CCSprite *firstSprite, *secondSprite;

 firstSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"firstSprite.png"];
 secondSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"secondSprite.png"];

 [firstSprite addChild:secondSprite];
 secondSprite.position = ccp(0,20) ;  // 20 points above
 [self addChild:firstSprite];
 firstSprite.position = ccp(100,100); // that moves secondSprite. the position of secondSprite
                                      // is relative to firstSprite
```

like that every time you move firstSprite, secondSprite moves along

ob cit: not tested, coded from memory.